# Compiling/parsing meaningful whitespace

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr

Hi I'm looking to make a pseudo Markdown kind of language and a parser to parse it into xhtml.

I've never written a compiler...  I've taken brief looks at ANTLR and am wondering if ANTLR can handle parsing things with meaningful whitespace?

So say I have something like this:

```
some text

  some other text

  # bullet point

    # nested bullet point
```

Depending on context and number of prefixing spaces, those lines would mean different things.

What is a good tool to use to write a parser for this?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR can surely be used for this. However, if you're new to ANTLR or parser-generators in general, I don't think I can give a short explanation of how to do this exactly. I recommend you try some simple things with ANTLR and browse through [The Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/tpantlr/index.html). It even has a paragraph about this type of problem which is similar to parsing Python code. See Chapter **4.3 Rules**, paragraph **Emitting More Than One Token per Lexer Rule** for details.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to make your lexer generate indent/outdent tokens. Store the current indentation level and match a pattern like `\n *`. Count the number of spaces and if it is different to the current indentation level, emit an indent/outdent token.

Similarly, count tabs at start-of-line. Inserting a rule that throws an error up on a pattern of `\n[ \t]*` should stop people mixing tabs and spaces.